# Hack Firefox to open extensions with address bar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I see this one time, and know that it not so hard, but can't find any solutions in internet.

Let say I have plugin, as you know it written by **XUL**. XUL like HTML has tags, js and etc. So I want to debug it with Firebug.

But in default plugin view firebug (as all other plugins disabled). So i need to open my plugin like Web page.

I remember that it's something like

```
chrome://address/to/my/plugin/page.xul
```

Does anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule by which you can build the addresses of extension pages. You have to open the extension's XPI file (it's a regular ZIP file, rename it if necessary) and have a look at `chrome.manifest` inside. E.g. in Firebug's `chrome.manifest` it says:

```
content firebug content/firebug/
```

Which means that the files in the `content/firebug/` directory of the extension are accessible under `chrome://firebug/content/`. You *can* try opening them as web pages but they won't necessarily work.

A better approach would be using tools that are actually meant for extensions. For example [Chromebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug) or [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/dom-inspector-6622/).

Comment: Thanks that will help me a lot.